# Linux RAW sockets

Tags: c, linux, network-programming, raw-sockets

I am working with RAW sockets on Linux/Debian and I have a problem when I use write() instead of sendto():

```
struct sockaddr_ll socket_address;
/* Index of the network device */
socket_address.sll_ifindex = if_idx.ifr_ifindex;
/* Address length*/
socket_address.sll_halen = ETH_ALEN;
/* Destination MAC */
socket_address.sll_addr[0] = 0x00;
socket_address.sll_addr[1] = 0x11;
socket_address.sll_addr[2] = 0x22;
socket_address.sll_addr[3] = 0x33;
socket_address.sll_addr[4] = 0x44;
socket_address.sll_addr[5] = 0x55;

/* Send packet */
int b_written = 0;

if ( ( b_written = write(sockfd, sendbuf, tx_len,
                                   (struct sockaddr*)&socket_address,
                                    sizeof(struct sockaddr_ll))) < 0 )
/*
if ( ( b_written = sendto(sockfd, sendbuf, tx_len, 0,
                                   (struct sockaddr*)&socket_address,
                    sizeof(struct sockaddr_ll))) < 0 )
*/
{
    perror("Could not write socket...");
    fprintf(stderr, "ERRNO = %d\n", errno);
    exit(-1);
}
printf("Packet sent!, Bytes written = %d\n", b_written);
```

If I use "write" instead of sendto, I get the following perror: "No such device or address" (errno=6, which is defined as EXNIO).

Using "sendto" I have no problem and packet is shown in "tcpdump -nettti eth0 '(ether dst host 00:11:22:33:44:55)'".

In accordance with man(sendto), sendto is equivalent to a write without specifying any flags. Since the flags field that I use for "sendto" is '0', I guess that both system calls are equivalent.

What migh I be doing wrong? Is it correct that both calls are equivalent?

Comment: `write()` can't have 5 parameters.

Comment: As for the contents of that manpage, it seems that the only differences between sendto() and sendmsg() are how to pass the arguments to those functions. Why should it be more appropriate to use "sendmsg()" than "sendto()" for a link layer level RAW socket?

Comment: Is this the original code. Did you mean `write` or `send`. What nouney said is right, i think. If it is `send`, then you cannot use it for connectionless service eg: SOCK_RAW

Comment: As you can see in the code, my issue is between the usage of "write" and "sendto". I started using "write" since the socket is connectionless; however, after getting the EXNIO error, I started using "sendto()" since I think that it does not require a connection to be established before sending data. In my case, the latter ("sendto()") is working fine and I can even see the packet with tcpdump.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sendto() call may be used only when the socket is in a connected state (so that the intended recipient is known). 
Following is the prototype of write function and it has 3 parameters not 5 like [send()](http://linux.die.net/man/2/send) function.

> write(int fd, const void *buf, size_t count);

Comment: Even with 3 arguments, I get the same errno #6 (EXNIO: "No such device or address"). The call to write is as follows: write(sockfd, sendbuf, tx_len).

Comment: A newer question that comes to my mind is: if in accordance with "write"'s manpage, this function has 3 arguments, why can I compile and execute my code passing 5 arguments to "write"? Does it support multiple arguments and ignores those that it does not need? Shouldn't GCC warn me (at least) about this issue?

Comment: @Ricardo No it don't support multiple arguments. What's your compiler option ? Did you compile with **-Wall** ?

Comment: I am using -Wall and GCC's output says "implicit declaration of function write"; however, the binary is generated and I can even execute it. Does GCC still generate the binary under these conditions? During the execution of this binary, shouldn't I expect the system to generate an error?

Comment: I think you need to call recvfrom(fd,....) with socket descriptor fd which saves the information of the side from which data is receiveed. and then call write(fd,..) using the same socket descriptor. Since while using write() you're not specifying the destination address explicitly and "fd" - the socket descriptor sepecifies where data is to be sent.

Comment: Or try using int `bind(
  _In_  SOCKET s,
  _In_  const struct sockaddr *name,
  _In_  int namelen
);`

Comment: @Ricardo Try with bind (take a look at my answer) and tell us if it solves your problem.

Comment: @Ricardo if you include `unistd.h`, gcc will tell you that you don't use it correctly.

Comment: @nouney , you are right: including "unistd.h" makes GCC throw out an error. However, does anybody know why GCC does not throw this error if I do not include "unistd.h"?

Comment: @Ricardo Because gcc needs to know the prototype of each used functions in your code. Without it, gcc will trust you :) (that's not a `write()`-specific thing, you can try with one of your own functions).

Comment: @nouney , OK, thanks for the explanation... I would never have thought that GCC would trust somebody like me... :)

Answer (score 3):

You have to `bind()` ([see manual](http://linux.die.net/man/2/bind)) the address to your socket, then use `write()` correctly (That means, with only **3** parameters).

```
/* Send packet */
int b_written = 0;

if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&socket_address, sizeof(struct sockaddr_ll)) == -1)
{
    perror("bind");
    exit(-1);
}
if ( ( b_written = write(sockfd, sendbuf, tx_len)) < 0 )
{
    perror("Could not write socket...");
    fprintf(stderr, "ERRNO = %d\n", errno);
    exit(-1);
}
printf("Packet sent!, Bytes written = %d\n", b_written);
```

Comment: Yes, this solves the problem. Thank you @nouney! Please find the full solution in my answer below since it is important to fill up certain fields of the sockaddr_ll structure.

Answer (score 0):

This message results from I/O to a special file's subdevice that either does not exist or that exists beyond the limit of the device. So check, Do you have permission or access to write where you want to perform write operation. Also change write parameters as it can have only three parameters.

from man page

```
int write(fd, buf, nbyte)
```

I hope this solve the issue.

Comment: why would he get an error for write but not sendto if it's a permission error?

Comment: Right now, I am executing that application as <root>, since I also need privileges for opening the socket; so I guess that it is not a permissions issue.

Comment: @Ricardo... I said that because you are getting errno=6, which means device not present. if you have that device physically(as I assumed), then there is only one problem. So check the device file. The permissions must read 666 (crw-rw-rw-).

Comment: @Krishna he said he sees the data in tcpdump, so the device clearly exists and he has permissions.